# Angular - Detect end of audio

Tags: angular

When user clicks a button, a function plays an audio file. When this file is finished, I need to call another function.

I cannot find a way to bind this event, i've tried adding onended on audio tag, attach a eventlistener through my component, setting player currentTime to 0 and i don't really know if Angular has a () or [] way of biding this state

What is the best/correct approach?

TEMPLATE:

```xml
    <div class="telaJogo container-fluid" *ngIf="showJogo">
     <audio id="player">
      <source src="/assets/vaifilhao.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.  
     </audio>
    <img src="/assets/play.png" alt="play" (click)="play()">
```

SERVICE:

```ts
    /**
    Gera próxima música a ser tocada
  */
  novaRodada(): void {
    console.log('cheguei aqui');
    let player = <HTMLAudioElement>document.getElementById("player");
    player.src = '/assets/Queen - Love of My Life.mp3';
    player.play();
  }
```

COMPONENT:

```ts
/**
    Toca a contagem e gera próxima música
  */
  play(): void {
    this.player.play();
    this.player.currentTime = 0;
  }

  /**
    Gera próxima música a ser tocada
  */
  novaRodada(): void {
    this.jogoService.novaRodada();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting when audio stopped playing:

```ts
const player = <HTMLAudioElement>document.getElementById("player");

Observable.fromEvent(player, 'ended').subscribe(console.log);
```

But it's realy not angular way. You could create directive and attach it to audio tag. Directives may contain `@Input`s so you can define what should be do on `ended` event.

In directive you can use `@HostListener('ended')`

See more: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#attribute-directives

Comment: `AudioModel` is already declared as `HTMLAudioElement`. It contains all stuff such as `play`, `paused` etc. see: https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/HTMLAudioElement/

Answer (score 4):

medias like audio and video triggers an event called onended once the media has reach its end. So you can attach a function direct to that event on the controller of your component like this.

*Notice the event (ended) on the audio tag element*

**audio.component.html**

```xml
<audio (ended)="audioEnded()" preload="auto" #audioPlayer>
    <source [src]="pathToTheSource" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

**audio.component.ts**

```ts
@ViewChild('audioPlayer') audioPlayer: ElementRef;

audioEnded(): void {
    console.log('ended!!')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way...

```
    play(): void {
    this.player.play();
    this.player.onended = function() {
        alert("The audio has ended");
     };
  }
```